# Solve alphametics puzzles in non-brute-force, iterative manner

Tags: ruby, iteration

The goal: Trying to optimize solution for the [alphametics problem on exercism](http://exercism.io/exercises/ruby/alphametics/readme).

From the question text:

> Alphametics is a puzzle where letters in words are replaced with numbers.
>
> For example SEND + MORE = MONEY:
>
> ```
>   S E N D
>   M O R E +
> -----------
> M O N E Y
> ```
>
> Replacing these with valid numbers gives:
>
> ```
>   9 5 6 7
>   1 0 8 5 +
> -----------
> 1 0 6 5 2
> ```
>
> Each letter must represent a different digit, and the leading digit of a multi-digit number must not be zero.

My approach: Rather than brute force trying every possible combination for all letters at once, I would like to try letters corresponding to the ones units first.  If a guess satisfies the ones units, use that guess as a starting point for trying the tens units.  And so on for as many places as the problem requires.

Rationale: Reduce the number of iterations overall by not wasting time with subsets of numbers that won't work for a subset of letters.

Here is my code that solves the puzzles but is very slow (puzzles with 8 letters take around 5-6 seconds and 10 letters MUCH longer).

```
class Alphametics
  class << self
    def solve(input)
      @input = input
      guess(@input)
    end

    def guess(input)
      letters_to_keys(input)
      left_most_digit_of_sum_max(input, @candidates)
      left_most_digit_is_not_0(first_letters(input), @candidates)
      generate_guess(@candidates)
    end

    def letters_to_keys(input) # create hash of letters and their possible values
      @candidates = {}
      letters(input).each {|ltr| @candidates[ltr] = (0..9).to_a}
      @candidates
    end

    def letters(input) # creates an array of unique letters from summands and sum
      (summands(input) + [sum(input)]).join.chars.uniq
    end

    def summands(input) #takes the input and separates summands from sum, removing the "+" character, returns array of "words" as strings
      input.split(" == ")[0].split(" + ")
    end

    def sum(input) # takes the input and separates sum from summands, returning a string of only letters
      input.split(" == ")[1]
    end

    def left_most_digit_of_sum_max(input, candidates) # the first digit of the sum has its value considerably constrained by the number summands when the sum has more digits than any of the individual summands
      if summands(input).all? {|word| word.length < sum(input).length}
        candidates[sum(input)[0]] = (0..summands(input).length-1).to_a
      end
    end

    def left_most_digit_is_not_0(letters, candidates) # the first digit of any number cannot be zero
      letters.each {|ltr| candidates[ltr] -= [0]}
    end

    def first_letters(input) # create an array of the first letter of each word -- for determining which letters cannot be zero
      a = []
      summands(input).each { |word| a << word[0]}
      a << sum(input)[0]
      a
    end

    def generate_guess(candidates)
      answer = {}
      potential_values = candidates.values
      letters = candidates.keys
      guess_index(potential_values).each do |i|
        dividend = i
        guess = []
        (0..potential_values.length-1).each do |ndx|
          divisor = potential_values[ndx].length
          if guess.include?(potential_values[ndx][dividend % divisor])
            next i
          else
            guess << potential_values[ndx][dividend % divisor]
            dividend = dividend / divisor
          end
        end
        if guess.length == potential_values.length && check_summation(letters, guess)
          answer = solution(guess, letters)
          return answer
        end
      end
      return answer
    end

    def guess_index(potential_values)
      index_length = 1
      potential_values.each { |vals| index_length*=vals.length }
      (0..index_length-1).to_a
    end

    def check_summation(letters, guess) # check that guess satisfies the summation
      nums = int_sub_for_letter(@input, letters, guess)
      summands(nums).collect{|x| x.to_i}.reduce(:+) == sum(nums).to_i
    end

    def int_sub_for_letter(input, letters, guess) # substitute numbers for letters in string
      string = input
      (0..guess.length-1).each do |i|
        string = string.gsub(letters[i], guess[i].to_s)
      end
      return string
    end

    def solution(guess, letters) # generate solution hash without mutating candidates hash
      letters.zip(guess).to_h
    end


  end
end
t1 = Time.now
p Alphametics.solve("SEND + MORE == MONEY")
t2 = Time.now
p t2-t1
```

I am trying to make this more efficient by reducing the number of iterations required.  I have done this by performing the calculation for each place (column if summation written vertically) sequentially.  Thus letters in the ones place that repeat elsewhere will have fewer potential values, leading to fewer permutations of guesses overall and thus fewer checks that the sum works out.

Comment: Hi there. here's my view: i don't like it because it's too difficult to read an d understand

Comment: Okay.  Anything more specific or suggestions for how to organize it differently to be easier to understand?

Comment: yessir i understand that my answer is vague and nebulous. the best way is to see good examples of refactoring with bad. here is a wonderful example - first note the complexity of the code in the question and compare it with the simplicity of the code in the answer - it's something we all should strive to emulate: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164100/validate-if-sudoku-is-correct/164485?noredirect=1#comment312828_164485

Comment: Have you tested this code? When I run it with Ruby 2.0.0, I get `in `block in solve': undefined method `to_h' for [["I", [1]], ["B", [2]], ["L", [3]]]:Array (NoMethodError)` on line 21. And with Ruby 2.3.1, I get `in `letters_to_chk': undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` on line 136.

Comment: I'm not sure when `to_h` was added, but I am generally using 2.3+.  As for the nil error, that is generated in the final iteration because there is already a solution.  I have not yet managed to get it to exit cleanly at that point.  When I posted to SO, I was told it would be better to post it here.  I've posted it here and have been told it is not appropriate either.  ::confused::

Comment: @200_success - I have edited the code such that it is working but less efficient than I would like.  I hope this is more in line with guidelines.

Comment: i've downloaded the exercism utility - there are forums etc where you can discuss this very problem

Comment: Yes, I had requested help on the exercism site and had also asked on the gitter exercism/xruby channel before asking on SE.

Comment: Thinking about how I'd do it manually: first check the ones column and make note of every combination that works, and for each of those, check the tens column for every combination that works (which will be a smaller set), and so forth. To track what's been tried, you can use a tree structure with the ones column options being the roots, so that when you run out of options at say, the hundreds column, you can prune the entire tree at the ones column because that combination will not lead to a solution. Hope you get what I'm saying.

Comment: A tree structure is not the only way to do it, it can also be done using  multiple stacks or recursion.

Comment: @MarkThomas Thanks for the suggestion.  The tree structure does sound workable.  I haven't been able to figure out a recursive method that works yet.  I will try and implement the tree approach.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried this and got my brute force solving the 10 letter test case in ~39 secs.  I'm not sure how fast the intended algorithm is meant to run, but based on [this thread](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51/alphametic-verbal-arithmetic-general-strategy) (note: "This all means that they'd be more accurately called linear programming problems, and integer linear programming is actually NP-hard in the abstract") there isn't a generalized efficient algorithm.  with ad hoc rules, you can likely pass these test cases fast but won't have a general algo.  would love to know if i'm wrong!

Comment: Researched this a bit more, and found [this page](https://enigmaticcode.wordpress.com/2016/06/22/solving-alphametics-with-python/) explaining that your method can be made to work quickly.  I believe it's not algorithmically guaranteed to be faster than brute force, but practically will almost always be.  You just work from the right column to the left column, assigning possibilities, and the short-circuit and backtrack when your reach a dead-end.  I'd imagine there's a nice recursive implementation of this.